# Twitter Bootstrap not found via Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, twitter-bootstrap

I´m learning Ruby on Rails and tried to implement Twitter Bootstrap. I know how to use and edit it, as I used it before - just without rails.

Setup was done, as suggested here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout?version=3.2#sec-custom_css - As I read this book.

The following error occurs: `File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.scss.` while trying to import `@import "bootstrap"`.

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.1.1.0'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
...
```

What do I wrong?
Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

Do I have to install "Compass" aswell? When checking with `gem server` I find under "bootstrap-sass" `bootstrap-sass 2.1.1.0 [rdoc] [www] - depends on compass, sass-rails.`

Comment: Please have a look at this https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass .May be it will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just followed the instruction in the link you provided and had no problem using bootstrap. I only did following steps:

1) edited the Gemfile so that the assets group would look like:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.1.1.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

2) created the file `app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss` and placed the following line:

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

3) generated a scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold posts title:string body:text date:date
```

4) migrated the database:

```
rake db:migrate
```

5) fired up the server

```
rails s
```

6) visit the posts page

```
http://localhost:3000/posts
```

You can view the view the generated css:

```
http://localhost:3001/assets/custom.css
```

where the bootstrap css is folded in.

Comment: The dependencies will be installed automatically when you do `bundle install`

Comment: Cheez... looks like the only problem was using single `'` instead of double `"` quotes... Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

`gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.1.1.0'` should be out of the `:assets` group. Just place it below `gem 'sqlite3-ruby`' and run `bundle install` again.

Comment: Fantastic. I downgraded to 2.1.1.0 since I was having trouble with 3.0. But great Thanks.