# Rails ignoring precompiled assets in S3, "could not find file 'bootstrap'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline

I'm precompiling assets locally and pushing them to S3. In production I get this error:

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=www.someapp.org fwd="76.87.106.226" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=614ms status=500 bytes=0
app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'bootstrap'
app[web.1]:   app/views/application/_stylesheets.html.erb:1:in `...'
app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `...'
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:11)):
app[web.1]:     1: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
```

When I run in production mode locally I do not get that error.

Here is my `application.rb`:

```
require File.expand_path("../boot", __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module SomeApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    require "ksp"
    require "markdowner"
    require "patches/carrier_wave"
    VERSION = "1.0.0"
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join("my", "locales", "*.{rb,yml}").to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record"s schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can"t be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = "1.0"

    config.generators do |generator|
      generator.test_framework :rspec, view_specs: false
    end

    config.assets.prefix = "/assets/#{Rails.env}"

    config.filepicker_rails.api_key = ENV["FILEPICKER_API_KEY"]

    # Allow for CORS requests
    config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins "*"
        resource "*", headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my `production.rb`:

```
SomeApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "d20eprk8nbwd96.cloudfront.net"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "www.someapp.org" }

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

Here is my `asset_sync.rb`:

```
if defined?(AssetSync) && !(ENV["HOME"] == "/app")
  AssetSync.configure do |config|
    config.fog_provider = "AWS"
    config.fog_directory = ENV["AMAZON_BUCKET"]
    config.aws_access_key_id = ENV["AMAZON_S3_KEY"]
    config.aws_secret_access_key = ENV["AMAZON_S3_SECRET"]

    # Increase upload performance by configuring your region
    config.fog_region = "us-west-2"
    #
    # Don't delete files from the store
    config.existing_remote_files = ENV["ASSET_SYNC_EXISTING_REMOTE_FILES"]
    #
    # Automatically replace files with their equivalent gzip compressed version
    config.gzip_compression = ENV["ASSET_SYNC_GZIP_COMPRESSION"]
    #
    # Use the Rails generated 'manifest.yml' file to produce the list of files to
    # upload instead of searching the assets directory.
    config.manifest = ENV["ASSET_SYNC_MANIFEST"]
    #
    # Fail silently.  Useful for environments such as Heroku
    # config.fail_silently = true
  end
end
```

Here is my `application.css`:

```
 /*
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require bootstrap-responsive
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require chosen
 *= require bootstrap/tour
 *= require bootstrap/lightbox
 *= require_self
 */
```

In production mode locally the method gives me the correct cloudfront URL.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: It happened this to me and I solved moving the `bootstrap` gem out of the `assets` group. It is not a new problem you can take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9213599/1004046 or here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13377374/1004046

Comment: Shouldn't I not have to do this since I'm precompiling?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out despite precompiling locally, Heroku was still trying to precompile on Heroku.

It would fail, and then try to compile the assets live. This would then fail in the way described.

I solved this by creating an empty file `/public/assets/manifest.yml`, even though my config says assets are in `/public/assets/production/`